# Indent every \subsubsection element

Tags: sectioning, indentation

I need to indent every `\subsubsection` element in my thesis.

I think that the solution is something like this

```
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{some-magic-here}
```

but i'm new of Latex and I have no idea in what kind of magic. ;)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: What document class are you using?

Comment: \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}

Comment: Do you need to indent both the subsubsection header and the associated material (i.e., until a higher-level sectioning header is encountered), or just the header, or just the material? I guess I'm not sure what you mean by "element".

Comment: I need to indent both header of subsubsection and its content.

Comment: This is not a very good typographic device.

Comment: I'm not interested in a good typographic device, it's about a technical thesis in informatics.

Comment: @RikyTres It's awful nonetheless.

Comment: Anyway, I know, you right! It's not good way...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The result is awful and I can see no reason for wanting this. But the document is yours.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{subs}
  {\adjustwidth{3em}{0pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{subs}
\subsubsection{One}

\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Two}

\lipsum[4]

\end{subs}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the following change, the subsubsection titles will be flush with the left margin. The result is even more awful than before.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newenvironment{subs}
  {\adjustwidth{2pc}{0pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}
  {-2pc}% <------- The opposite of what we set for subs
  {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\lipsum[1]

\subsection{A subsection}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{subs}
\subsubsection{One}

\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Two}

\lipsum[4]

\end{subs}

\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

Comment: If i want to leave the header of the sub subsection in its position?

Comment: @RikyTres It's even worse. I'll add the code, but not a picture.

Comment: The `\adjustwidth` seems not working with `\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]`, it generates a weird error: "perhaps a missing \item".

Comment: @YanKingYin That’s a very different problem, I believe. Please, ask a new question with all details.

Comment: New question is here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/400416/error-when-trying-to-indent-a-run-in-subsection

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\leftskip 0pt\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subsection{\leftskip 0pt\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\Xsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\leftskip 3ex}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection[1]{\Xsubsubsection{#1}\leftskip 3ex}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{My section}

\lipsum[4]

\subsection{My subsection}

\lipsum[4]

\subsubsection{My subsubsection\label{xxx}}

In subsection \ref{xxx}, we have the indent.

\subsection{Next subsection}

\lipsum[4]

\section{next section}

\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've implemented this, but itemize lists within the subsections are not having the indent. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: @MosheSteinberg Without more information, it is tough to say.