# Error when trying to indent a run-in subsection

Tags: sectioning, indentation, titlesec

For some reason I cannot indent a `\subsubsection{}` that is formatted by the `titlesec` package using the `[runin]` option.  The run-in option is for making the paragraph follow immediately after the `\subsubsection{}` heading, which in my case I leave it blank and use only the numbers.

The file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}

\subsection{} This is a paragraph:

\begin{quote}
\subsubsection{} This is a sub-paragraph I want to indent.
\end{quote}

{\addtolength{\leftskip}{5mm}
\subsubsection{} This is a sub-paragraph I want to indent.
}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following output:

[image]

Notice that the first method works, but it makes an error:

> Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

The second method does nothing at all.

Now if I remove the `[runin]` option both methods work just as expected.  It seems that the `[runin]` option interferes with indentation.  However, despite the error the first method seems to produce the desired document.  Any idea how to eliminate the error?

Comment: Do you want all subsubsection titles to be run-in and indented?

Comment: The `quote` environment is implemented as a list, so you can't embed a section inside it. That's why you get the error. Do you want all `subsubsection`s to be indented? If so, then use `titlesec` to do that.

Comment: Yes, I want all `\subsubsection`s to be indented, how should I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You're better using `\titlespacing`. The last two parameters are taken from the values in `article.cls`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{} This is a paragraph:
\lipsum[2]

\subsubsection{} This is a sub-paragraph I want to indent.
\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to indent the whole block, then `adjustwidth` can do it, but for implementation reasons you need to issue `\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}`. The problem is that `adjustwidth` is implemented as a list and this conflicts with run-in titles.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsubsection.}{3pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{} This is a paragraph:
\lipsum[2]

\begin{adjustwidth}{\parindent}{0pt}\mbox{}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\subsubsection{} This is a sub-paragraph I want to indent.
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A perhaps better implementation with a proper environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\let\subsubaw\adjustwidth
\xpatchcmd{\subsubaw}
  {\topsep}
  {\labelwidth=0pt \labelsep=0pt \topsep}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\subsubaw}
  {\item[]}
  {\refstepcounter{subsubsection}\item[\thesubsubsection.\hspace{3pt} ]}
  {}{}
\newenvironment{subsub}
 {\par\addvspace{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}%
  \subsubaw{\parindent}{0pt}}
 {\endadjustwidth}

\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{}{\thesubsection.}{3pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{This is a section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{} This is a paragraph:
\lipsum[2]

\begin{subsub}
This is a sub-paragraph I want to indent.
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{subsub}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, by "indentation" I mean the whole block should be indented, not just the heading... can that be done?

Comment: @YanKingYin Added the workaround

Comment: Is there no way to automate this?

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes, see last version

Comment: Great! Then you should also add that as an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109328/how-can-i-get-legal-style-indentation-on-section-subsection-subsubsec-using