# Indent Whole paragraphs after subsections

Tags: sectioning, indentation

Basically, I need to indent paragraphs after a subsection as shown here:

[image: example]

Basically, I need to indent the all the content after a subsection. I already have the proper formatting for the heading of the subsection as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}    
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\bfseries\itshape\normalsize\hspace{2em}}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I found a solution here: [Indenting a whole paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph)

However, the problem is that in order to apply the solution I will need to manually add code before and after each subsection.

Another solution here: [Indent every \subsubsection element](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153846/indent-every-subsubsection-element)

proposes using a new environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum} 
\newenvironment{subs}
  {\adjustwidth{3em}{0pt}}
  {\endadjustwidth}
\begin{document}
\subsection{A subsection}


\lipsum[2]

\begin{subs}
\subsubsection{One}

\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Two}

\lipsum[4]

\end{subs}
\end{document}
```

However, this has the same problem: I would need to manually add `\begin...\end` of the environment for each subsection I have. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Automation of this is hard to do because the sectioning commands are not environments (an unfortunate design choice in some ways).  So as a result, you can't hook into the end of a section/subsection etc. which is what you would need to have this work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same spirit as your first [quoted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph) and using `etoolbox`'s `patchcmd` you can assume that `\leftskip` is not used dor anything else, the magic is :

```
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}{}{}
```

which switches off the shift at the beginning of the `\section` and `\subsection`, and switches it on when entering into `\subsection`. Here is a MWE, in the which I changed the page size to fit the example on two pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}{3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{0cm}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subsection}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex}{1.5ex \@plus .2ex\setlength{\leftskip}{2cm}}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{3}
\section{Section Foo}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{A subsection}\label{s:first}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{Another subsection}
\lipsum[3-5]

\section{Section Bar}
\textbf{As seen in section \ref{s:first}}
\lipsum[5]
\subsection{Test again}
\lipsum[5]
\end{document}
```

with the result:
[image]

**Note 1:** this works also with `hyperref`, provided you make the patch before loading it.

**Note 2:** This approach is likely *not* compatible with `titlesec`. It assumes that the sectioning commands (below `\chapter`) are based on the standard `\@startsection` command. This is not an issue as you can also patch in a similar way the format of the title for getting italic

**Note 3:** To determine the value of the second argument of `\patchcmd` (which depends on the class and ptsize) you have to look at the content of the  sectionng commands. For this purpose I use a custom command :

```
\newcommand{\mymeaning}[1]{{\small\noindent{\bfseries \string #1} = \meaning #1\par\medskip}}
```

based on the standard command `\meaning` with some cosmetic, and do  e.g. `\mymeaning{\subsection}` in the document.

Comment: If you have chapters or part, ending a subsection  you would have to apply to the corresponding command the same patch as for section, disabling the shift. I will soon provide the patch for the standard \chapter. An other option (for chaoter) would be to alter the clearpage command.